# Parse TWIG strings to add &nbsp; before punctuation markers

Tags: regex, symfony, twig

I search a way to parse strings in TWIG.

I have a translation file: messages.fr.yml and I call strings like that: `{{ 'bloc.name'|trans() | raw }}`.

In french, before some punctuation markers there is a space. The problem is when the sentence is cut between the end ant the marker. So I want to replace each space before these markers: `[ ? , ! , ; , : ]` by `&nbsp;`.

I though about a solution which could use autoescape + regex but I do not know how can I do that and if it is the best way to do. Someone has an idea?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for : how to create your own Twig Filter.

It is possible with a Twig Extension : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('nbspace', array($this, 'nbspace'))
        );
    }

    public function nbspace($sentence)
    {
        return preg_replace('/ ([\?!;:])/',' $1',$sentence);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Then you have to enable this filter in services.yml like this :

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

To use it :

```
{{ 'bloc.name'|trans() | nbspace | raw }}
```

No need to change the autoescaping stategy in your use case.

If you want to avoid the 'raw' filter, you can also specify that your filter returns something 'safe for html' :

```
new \Twig_SimpleFilter('nbspace', array($this, 'nbspace'), array('is_safe'=>array('html')))
```

Comment: filter definition does not match it's callback. It's also better to return a `Twig_Markup`, marking the content as safe so you don't need to add `raw` as filter: `return new \Twig_MarkUp(preg_replace('/ ([\?!;:])/',' $1',$sentence), 'UTF-8');` --> `{{ 'bloc.name'|trans() | nbspace }}`

Comment: Never heard anything about 'Twig_Markup' ?, if the filter aims to return safe html, he must add the option 'is_safe'=>['html'] to the Twig_SimpleFilter contructor. But I don't think it was the topic of the question.